# Irreducible components of $\partial \bar{H}_{g,n}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, moduli-spaces, stacks

Let $\bar{H}_{g,n}$ be the moduli space (or moduli stack) of $n$-pointed stable hyperelliptic curves. I am interested in understanding its rational Picard group.

In the case $n=0$, the rational Picard group is generated by the irreducible components of the boundary $\partial\bar{H}_{g,n}$, and these are linearly independent. The boundary components are obtained by intersecting those of $\bar{M}_{g,n}$ with $\bar{H}_{g,n}$, all but one components remain irreducible. The way this is proved is by considering maps from the ausiliary moduli of admissible double covers. One then proves that they are linearly independent, for example this is done in Geometry of Algebraic Curves II, page 391 (thm 8.4). All of this I think I understand well.

Has the analogous procedure been carried out somewhere for $n>0$? I am having trouble generalizing the definition of admissible covers to $n$-pointed admissible covers. For example, if I take them to be $(\pi:C\to D, p_1,\dots,p_n\in C$ not in the ramification locus of $\pi$, $(D,\pi(p_i), B)$ stable, where $B$ is the branch divisor of $\pi$) then after contraction I don't get those hyperelliptic stable marked curves such that the involution is ramified at the markings.

Comment: This is not precisely $\overline{H}_{g,n}$, nonetheless, you might look at the moduli space $\overline{\mathcal{K}}_{0,n}(B(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\beta_g)$ of twisted stable maps to the classifying stack $B(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ studied by  Abramovich and Vistoli.  When $n$ equals $0$, this equals the space $\overline{H}_g$ of admissible double covers.